# Firefox div background 1px wider than border, but only with certain content lengths

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm having an issue with a `<div>` I use to display messages to users. It's very basic stuff. But in FireFox, the background is sometimes wider than the border. See the attached image. The three blocks are exactly the same except the content, but only the middle one has the extra 1px to the right.

First I though it had something to do with Bootstrap. But the issue is still there with a very basic page. Has anyone a quick fix or do I need to use a parent container and rewrite the message code entirely.
Tried to experiment with the font size, padding etc but then it simply appears when a different text length is shown.

I use FireFox v 81.0

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body style="background-color: #181818">

    <style>
        .vdwwd_messages {
            font-family: Verdana;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: fixed;
            top: 23%;
            left: 50%;
            min-width: 400px;
            max-width: 800px;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
            background-color: #fce7e7;
            border: 8px solid #bf1616;

            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; //does nothing
        }
    </style>

    <div class="vdwwd_messages">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </div>

    <div class="vdwwd_messages" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx
    </div>

    <div class="vdwwd_messages" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xx
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Different content widths**

```
<div class="vdwwd_messages">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>

<div class="vdwwd_messages" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx
</div>

<div class="vdwwd_messages" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: outline: 1px solid #bf1616; ?

Comment: or box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #bf1616; ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, adding an outline of 1px or just adding `outline: 8px solid #bf1616;` instead of the border fixes the issue. Thanks! Still I'm wondering if this is a firefox bug...

Comment: not really a bug but subpixel rendring. You face this at least once in your life

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dropping `position` + `transform` will avoid those bug rendering and futur headaches.

`grid` could be an option to set every box at 100px from the top of the previous one, and the buggy one pixel bg will be gone.

```css
body {
  background-color: #181818;
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:100px;
}
.vdwwd_messages {
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  background-color: #fce7e7;
  border: 8px solid #bf1616;
}
```

```html
  <div class="vdwwd_messages">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </div>

  <div class="vdwwd_messages" >
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx
  </div>

  <div class="vdwwd_messages" >
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xx
  </div>
```